# Why is the assert not getting imported here

Tags: python

I have the following unit test case.

```
import unittest
from webPageTestUtils import WebPageTestProcessor

class webPageUtilsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.webPageTestProcessor = WebPageTestProcessor()

    def test_submitTest(self):
        url = None;
        assertEqual(self.webPageTestProcessor.submitTest(url),None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Upon execution I get an error saying.

`NameError: global name 'assertEqual' is not defined`

I have subclassed unittest.TestCase , then why is python not recognizing assert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a method on `self`:

```
self.assertEqual(self.webPageTestProcessor.submitTest(url), None)
```